# How to easily switch to another SVN branch in PyCharm Django Project

Tags: python, django, svn, version-control, pycharm

I have a PyCharm Django project, versioned with SVN. Project itself been created via "Checkout from version control" function, and root of a project is a root of repository, so it includes trunk and branches. 
My questions is:
- How to easily switch between feature-branches?
- Maybe Im missing something - what in that case good style to work with PyCharm and SVN?

ps
Branches in my case are created frequently - new one for every specific feature-set, and by completeness they reintegrates into trunk.

Comment: I think you should check out only one branch and then use `relocate` function to swith to other branch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ended up with this style:

- At first I create a directory where I will place a project version with which I intend to work
- Then I checkout in that directory a branch or trunk
- Do needed changes
- Commit
- And then if I need to switch to another branch or trunk I invoke "update project" in "VCS" menu ([link to docs](http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/webhelp/update-project-dialog-subversion.html))
  and then, in Update/Switch field specify another branch. For complete switching, "depth" must be "infinity", for ful recursive scan of files, and selector "force update" must be checked for declining local modifications.
  [image]
- If I need to merge - I switch to trunk and then use "merge from" in "VCS" menu

Answer (score 1):

You can open trunk/branches with multiple pycharm window. The project root should be trunk/branch root.

Normally, you don't need to switch among branches frequently.